# Ambiguity in recurrent neural network training in Julia Flux

Tags: machine-learning, julia, recurrent-neural-network, flux.jl

I'm using Julia's Flux library to learn about neural networks.  According to the documentation for `train!` (where `train!` takes arguments `(loss, params, data, opt)`):

> For each datapoint d in data, compute the gradient of loss with respect to params through backpropagation and call the optimizer opt.

(see source for `train!`: https://github.com/FluxML/Flux.jl/blob/master/src/optimise/train.jl)

For a conventional NN based on `Dense` -- let's say with a one-dimensional input and output, i.e. with one feature -- this is easy to understand.  Each element in `data` is a pair of single numbers, an independent sample of 1-d input/output values.  `train!` does forward- and backpropagation on each pair of 1-d samples one at a time.  In the process, the `loss` function is evaluated on each sample.  (Do I have this right?)

My question is: how does this extend to a recurrent NN?  Take the case of an RNN with 1-d (i.e. one feature) input and output.  It seems like there's some ambiguity in how to structure the input and output data, and the results change based on the structure.   As one example:

```
x = [[1], [2], [3]]
y = [4, 5, 6]
data = zip(x, y)
m = RNN(1, 1)
opt = Descent()
loss(x, y) = sum((Flux.stack(m.(x), 1) .- y) .^ 2)
train!(loss, params(m), data, opt)
```

(`loss` function taken from: https://github.com/FluxML/Flux.jl/blob/master/docs/src/models/recurrence.md)

In this example, when `train!` loops through each sample (`for d in data`), each value of `d` is a pair of single values from `x` and `y`, e.g. `([1], 4)`.  `loss` is evaluated based on these single values.  This is the same as in the `Dense` case.

On the other hand, consider:

```
x = [[[1], [2], [3]]]
y = [[4, 5, 6]]
m = RNN(1, 1)
opt = Descent()
loss(x, y) = sum((Flux.stack(m.(x), 1) .- y) .^ 2)
train!(loss, params(m), zip(x, y), opt)
```

Note that the only difference here is that `x` and `y` are nested in an extra pair of square brackets.  As a result there's only one `d in data`, and it's a pair of sequences: `([[1], [2], [3]], [4, 5, 6])`.  `loss` can be evaluated on this version of `d`, and it returns a 1-d value, as required for training.  But the value returned by `loss` is different than in any of the three results from the previous case, so the training process turns out differently.

The point is that both structures are valid in the sense that `loss` and `train!` handle them without error.  Conceptually, I can make an argument for both structures being correct.  But the results are different, and I assume that only one way is right.  In other words, for training an RNN, should each `d in data` be a whole sequence, or a single element from a sequence?

Comment: When quoting from something available online (including the documentation), please also post the relevant link.